# How do I block users from creating a Hotspot while using our internet network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

We have organized a wi-fi network through Tp-Link (Omada Controller). Users connect to our network (via an external portal) and can use the Internet. But some users are sharing hotspot while connected to our network. We must limit this possibility. That is, if someone distributes a hotspot while connected to our network, we have to restrict the internet access for that user. Kerio Controller is also installed from us. But neither Kerio Controller documentation nor Tp-Link documentation has any information about this. I also searched on Google, but no one gave a solution. I heard about ubuntu ttl 64, 128. However, I couldn't find any information on how to do this in practice. I have seen people who have solved my problem but I have not been able to contact them. When I connect to a network and share a hotspot, the internet does not work. But I couldn't find out how they did it.
How to solve this problem? Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Which operating system are used by the users? Is this a domain, or are you in some kind of control over the users?

Comment: Also, what country are you in?

Comment: @harrymc Can connect to the network using any operating system. We control users through Kero Controller. But if they connect to our network and spread the wifi hotspot, we can't control them. Internet access is managed through the Omada Controller. But we can't control hotspot distribution with it.

Comment: "I have seen people who have solved my problem" - can you link to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two means for detecting if a network package is
coming from the primary user or from a secondary (hotspot),
as follows:

- Verifying that the MAC address on the package is that of the
  primary user.
- Checking the TTL (Time To Live).
  Every package sent through the net has TTL which decreases by one
  every time that it's redirected from one device to another.
  The default TTL value is 128 for desktops and 64 for mobile.

If the software you're using is capable of doing one of the
above checks, then it is feasible to limit your users in this way.
Otherwise, you might need to get a more evolved hardware router
or routing software.

For TTL, setting TTL=2 in the router on incoming packages will
mean that they can make only one hop up to the primary user before
being discarded, so they won't arrive to a secondary user.
Knowledgeable users can change the TTL back, but most people
won't be able to.

If the router is based on Linux, then this is possible using
`iptables`. Otherwise, consult its firmware manual to see if
it has such an option.

One reference that might help :
[Avoid Internet Sharing on Hotspot - Change TTL | MIKROTIK HOTSPOT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYBLXzGhPQQ)
(YouTube)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I use TTL? Is there any additional software for this? We couldn't find a clear answer from Google. We couldn't find these things in either the Kerio Controller or the Tp-Link Omada Controller.

Comment: I added more information.